# Jenkins Pipeline - Why does the Pipeline option not show up

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins Jenkins ver. 2.82 running and would like to use the Pipeline function when creating a new job. But I dont see this listed as option. I can only choose between free-style Project, maven Project, external Project and multiconfigruation. How can I use the Pipeline option, as for example explained here: http://www.jhipster.tech/setting-up-ci-jenkins2/ . I tried to find a solution, but yet I was not successfull. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you didn't install all the appropriate plugins when you installed Jenkins. I think this is the main one you need. All the dependencies should come with it. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin

Comment: Thank you very much. This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install the [Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) plugin.